# What are the time labels on the left side of Chrome DevTools source file tabs?

Tags: performance, electron, google-chrome-devtools

**Short question:** what are these time labels and what makes them appear on the sources tab?
[image]

**Additional info:**

- I'm using electron + vue starting from this boilerplate: https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue
- they appear when a performance profile is loaded
- they disappear when the performance tab is cleared
- they don't match the other numbers given by DevTools (for example the bottom-up view gives 7.0 ms as total time for this function for the complete profile but sources panel shows 8.9 ms constantly)
- this is on the renderer process
- I tried Vue template from here https://electronforge.io/templates and these labels didn't show up
- they are not shown for web pages either

I suspect there is a DevTool extension in the project but I couldn't find what it is and Googling didn't help either.

Comment: Those are shown when profiling using the old "JavaScript Profiler" panel in devtools which you can reveal using the devtools menu. Generally the timing should be similar.

Comment: I used the "Performance" panel for creating the profile. But your comment made me think that it's an older devtools feature which exists in the project only because it uses an older electron with an older chrome. But why isn't this feature described anywhere?

Comment: Ah indeed it's shown there too in Canary, but wasn't shown for quite a few previous versions of Chrome. It's probably described in some very old documentation for devtools when the feature was introduced.